# How to call a plugin function from index.php

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, permalinks

I have created a function in my plugin `myplugin` with the name `foo`, how to call it from the frontend?

```
 e.g. index.php?
```

Comment: hmmm a 25% acceptance rate is pretty low

Comment: How to call a PHP function within a PHP file is a **PHP** question, not a **WordPress** question.

Comment: its literally a question about wordpress plugins @ChipBennett ....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The same way you would any other:

```
foo();
```

Active plugins are loaded before the theme files

You may want to check that your plugin is activated and the function is available so things dont go pear-shaped if you forget to activate it, like:

```
if(function_exists('foo')){
    foo();
} else {
    echo "oh dear you haven't activated/installed 'myplugin', go do that before the 'foo' feature is available";
}
```

Also keep in mind `foo` is a very generic function name, perhaps the "omgfoo" plugin also has a `foo` function. So prefix/namespace your function to something unique

You will eventually want to use actions and filters, as they're safer and better practice, [you can continue to read up on that here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71997/how-to-not-show-plugin-in-admin-area/71999#71999)

Answer (score 5):

You don’t. A Theme should not rely on a plugin except in a very controlled environment. Use [actions and filters](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71997/how-to-not-show-plugin-in-admin-area/71999#71999) instead.

So in your theme you might use:

```
do_action( 'before_header' );
```

… or …

```
$bg_options = array (
    'wp-head-callback' => 't5_custom_background_frontend',
    'default-color'    => 'f0f0f0',
    'default-image'    => '',
);
$bg_options = apply_filters( 't5_theme_bg_options', $bg_options );
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $bg_options );
add_action( 'login_head', $bg_options['wp-head-callback'] );
```

In your plugin you use `add_action()` and `add_filter()` to change or add new content. This way the theme will still work when the plugin has been deactivated and you don’t have to use `function_exists()`.

Answer (score 2):

Active plugins are loaded (as in technically - their files are *included* and processed by PHP during WordPress load) by the time theme templates run.

So your function should be available and can be called as any other function:

```
<?php foo(); ?>
```

for example.